# View transform pivot point while moving geometry in edit mode

Tags: 3d-view, transforms, axis

Is there a way, to view the transform pivot point while moving geometry in edit mode? I was trying to move a circle, so that its center would be aligned with another part of the model, it would have been really nice to see the median point for that (I ended up adding a cube to the center and deleting it after I was done).

Comment: I meant in edit mode; edited the question appropriately.

Comment: Got you...  I often have various home-made jigs lying around to do that kind of thing, too.. although in this particular case, I would snap with the Median of the circle, to a suitable target?

Comment: I did not know snapping had so much optinos, I actually never used it... Yeah, that works

Comment: e.g.   ..align view to a face  with Shift-Numpad 7, and restrict movement parallel to the viewing-plane by snapping in 'View' transform orientation, Shift-Z.